# New Features Angular 1.2

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in AngularJS and I came using the release (1.0.5), however I think update me to release 1.2.

I need know what are the main issues that I should consider in order to my app continue working?.

If possible tell me aobut the new and main features of AngularJS Versión 1.2 regard to previous releases ej. (1.0.5).

Comment: Check out the angular blog, covers a lot of the changes http://blog.angularjs.org/

Comment: The best change is that you can reload the page and view the contents using 
`app.run (['$ route', angular.noop]);`

Answer (score 2):

+1 on checking out the blog but more importantly look at the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). Specifically look at the "breaking changes" listed for each release which should cover any updates that would actually break your app. Keep in mind issues may also be caused by libraries that rely on Angular.js when you upgrade (ex. Angular UI).

Comment: Thanks Justin. The section "breaking changes" is perfect.